# ng not found despite installing

Tags: angular, npm

[image]

I have installed npm and also typed the command "npm install -g @angular/cli" despite that when I try to use ng command it's showing 'ng' is not recognized as internal or external command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found my solution. After the installation it didn't add the @angular/bin path into my environment. Also I had to change the default opener of .js files to Node.exe.